# Guru Goraksha Kimayagar

Tags: translation-request

Is it possible to get a copy of Guru Goraksha Kimayagar? I have searched about it but no one seems to know. A poet saint shri Malu Narhari ji in 17th century converted it into a Marathi in a poetic form known as Navnath Bhaktisaar. That is is available in different languages today. But is it possible to get the original one?